# Backup and restore single file?

Tags: backup, mysql, restore, nano

I am planning to change my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file in **Nano**. I have 2 questions about this:

1. Before I do this, is there a way to make a backup of this file?
2. If something goes wrong, how can I restore the file from the backup (from question 1.)?

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate post. Please let me know if this has been discussed elsewhere and if you have a link that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as making a copy of the file. Then, if something goes wrong, you can just delete your modified file and rename the copy.

I would do:

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

To restore:

```
sudo rm /etc/mysql/my.cnf
sudo mv /etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal file so you can `cp` top create a backup

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.backup
```

and restore it

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf.backup  /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

You may use whatever file name and path you want instead of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.backup`